# How to unit test hystrix fallback with spring-cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I've implemented an http call with feign and hystrix following the following article : https://blog.crafties.fr/2017/07/23/setup-a-circuit-breaker-with-hystrix/

I'm using those dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

My implementation looks like this :

```
@FeignClient(name = "someName", 
url = "https://my.url/to/service", fallbackFactory = RTKClientFallbackFactory.class)
public interface RTKClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/topics/rt/messages")
    KRestProducerResponse sendT(@RequestBody T t);

}


@Component
public class RTKClientFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<RTKClient>{

    @Override
    public RTKClient create(Throwable cause) {
        return new RTKClientFallback(cause);
    }
}

public class RTKClientFallback implements RTKClient{

    private final Throwable cause;
    private final static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(RTKClientFallback.class);

    public RTKClientFallback(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    @Override
    public KRestProducerResponse sendTemplate(T t) {
        KRestProducerResponse response = new KRestProducerResponse();
        if (cause instanceof FeignException) {
            response.setStatus(((FeignException)cause).status());
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

This works when I test it manually.
The issue for me is to unit test the fallback

This is how I tried :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients
public class RTKClientFallbackTest {

    @Autowired
    public RTKClient client;

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);

    @Test
    public void should_fall_back_with_error_code_in_response() {

        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("https://my.url/to/service/v1/topics/rt/messages"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(404)));
        T t = new T();
        KRestProducerResponse response = client.sendTemplate(t);
        assertEquals(404, response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is the following things :

- How to link my stub and my FeignClient ? (as of now, my test calls the real endpoint)
- How can I enable hystrix in this context (If I make it fail my messing up the url, I see it's not using the fallback)

Any ideas are welcome.
Thank you

Comment: I understood that wiremock exposes an endpoint on localhost:8089 so I need my FeignClient to use this endpoint.
Testing the fallback is still a problem for me

Comment: have you set `feign.hystrix.enabled=true`?

Comment: No, I hadn't this in my application.yml for my tests ! I fell so dumb
Thank you spencergibb !!!